# Understanding code about inverse transform sampling R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, uniform-distribution

I am trying to understand the following code about Inverse Transform Sampling (Discrete example)

```
    discrete.inv.transform.sample <- function( p.vec ) {
  U  <- runif(1)
  if(U <= p.vec[1]){
    return(1)
  }
  for(state in 2:length(p.vec)) {
    if(sum(p.vec[1:(state-1)]) < U && U <= sum(p.vec[1:state]) ) {
      return(state)
    }
  }
}

num.samples <- 1000
p.vec        <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3)
names(p.vec) <- 1:4
samples     <- numeric(num.samples)
for(i in seq_len(num.samples) ) {
  samples[i] <- discrete.inv.transform.sample(p.vec)
}
barplot(p.vec, main='True Probability Mass Function')
```

My first question is in the function `discrete.inv.transform.sample(p.vec)` in the first part `return(1)`, where is this `1` value when returned?

And in the second part, `return(state)` where is this `state` allocated?

- Why is this line `names(p.vec)<-1:4` for ?
- What `seq_len` means ?
- Why `samples[i]` is not used anymore in the code?

I think there should be a stand alone line `sample`

Could someone please explain?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to do some basic research on R and programming in general. Here are short answers to your simple questions, but please read on afterward for some broader advice.

- Where is the `1` value when returned? Wherever it is assigned. Here, namely in `samples[i]` for whichever `i` that branch is reached.
- Where is this `state` allocated? In the line `for(state in 2:length(p.vec))`
- Why is this line `names(p.vec)<-1:4` for? Good question. `names()<-` just assigns names to an object, and I'm not sure why in your context it's useful to have names that are equal to the vector indices, though I could imagine it to be so in some contexts.
- What `seq_len` means? `seq_len(x)` creates an integer vector with all the numbers from `1` to `x` inclusive. See `help("seq_len")`
- Why `samples[i]` is not used anymore in the code? Because it's only useful in the for loop.

All this points to a bigger problem though: You don't understand the basics of R. We all started out there, but it means you need to read some basic info and work through some basic tutorials. RStudio provides some resources for learning [here](https://www.rstudio.com/online-learning/).

Comment: Thank you, notice I am starting with this:) .In the second bullet, I meant that if `state` was allocated outside this function. Will `state` be also part of `i` here: `samples[i]` ?

Comment: `state` is local to the function `discrete.inv.transform.sample`

Comment: I am not understanding the idea, it's supposed that when returning 1, then X=1.Else X=state. Where is this in the output?

Comment: I do understand the basics of R, it's just that I find very difficult to code the algorithm in R.  So I thought in a program already done

Comment: OK, I see. The *value* of `state` will be returned in that case, and assigned to `samples[i]`

Comment: why did you say `state` is local then?

Comment: @Isa Because the variable `state` is only in the scope of the function, but its *value* will be returned

Comment: @Isa *"I do understand the basics of R"* No offence, but I really doubt that from your questions and comments. I would *strongly* recommend following duckmayr's advice to do some research on basic R coding. SO is not an R tutorial service, and mistakenly assuming SO to be that often leads to disappointment (and down votes) on both sides.